# Jenkins - Git clone command not working on shell

Tags: jenkins, github

I have a very simple JOB in Jenkins on a Windows 10 machine, which is aimed to clone a github repo into a dir when triggered.

It's simple a Windows shell including a command `git clone xxx some_output_dir`: I'm not using GIT plugin.

This command will run forever and goes in timeout.

If I run manually in CMD it works perfectly.

Any idea on which setting I may need to look at?

output directory rights are correctly set.

Is there any convenient way to do so?

Comment: Is the Jenkins user authorized to access the GitHub repository?

Comment: Sorry, but how can I check it? I've saved the Github account after 1 time i tryed on cmd shell.

Comment: Run `git config --global --list` from Jenkins and see if it returns `github.user=xxxx` and `github.token=xxxxxx`. Else configure them.

Comment: sorry but how can I configure via Jenkins shell?